# BufferedImage/Image Conversion

Tags: java, image, swing

When loading an image using ImageIO, you are returned a `BufferedImage`. I used this `BufferedImage` in the function `java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(int,int,int,int)`. Now... I need to print some of these `BufferedImage`'s, but the `java.awt.Graphics.drawImage(Image,int,int,null)` function takes in an `Image`, not a `BufferedImage`. How to convert a `BufferedImage` to an `Image`?
Code:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class engine{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GUI();
                }
            });
        }
    private static void GUI(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Daealia");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    f.add(new p());
    f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
class p extends JPanel{
    public p(){}
        public engine eng = new engine();   
        public BufferedImage[][] spells;
        public BufferedImage image;
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(new Color(82,41,0));
            g.fillRect(0,0,74,254);
            g.setColor(new Color(16,8,0));
            g.drawRect(0,0,74,254);
            try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("spells.png"));} catch(IOException e){System.out.println("EXCEPTION THROWN!");
            }
            for(int k = 0; k <= 6; k++){
                spells[k][1] = image.getSubimage((34*2*k)-34*2,0,34,34);
            }
            for(int j = 0; j <= 6; j++){
                spells[j][2] = image.getSubimage((34*2*j)-34,0,34,34);
            }
            for(int a = 0; a <= 6; a++){
                for(int b = 0; b <= 1; b++){
                    g.drawImage(spells[a][b],1+((b-1)*34),1+((a-1)*34),null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at p.paintComponent(engine.java:51)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1045)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1031)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1647)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at p.paintComponent(engine.java:51)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1045)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1031)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1967)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3877)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1647)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: You still haven't told us what line throws the exception. What line is `engine.java:51`, line 51 of your class?

Comment: line 51 is
        spells[k][1] = image.getSubimage((34*2*k)-34*2,0,34,34);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A BufferedImage ***is*** an Image, in other words it extends from the Image abstract class. You don't need to convert anything.

Please check out the [BufferedImage API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) for the details.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> When I run this code, I get spammed with errors in my console. Why would it do this? When the java file is converted into a class it has no errors found.

Then you'll want to post any error/exception messages that you receive, and also indicate for us which line(s) throw them.

Also as an aside, you will **never** want to read in an image from within a paintComponent method. This method should be lean, mean, and fast as hell, and it should concern itself with painting and painting only. Why read in the image multiple times when you only need to read it into a variable once say in the constructor?

---

**Edit 2**
Your error is a NullPointerException that occurs on `engine.java:51`, on line 51 of your engine.java class. Note that this has **nothing** to do with use of BufferedImage vs. Image, and everything to do with trying to use a null reference variable. As I suspected, the key to the problem is in the exception message. In your future questions, you will want to post any and all exception messages **and** indicate which line throws them.

---

**Edit 3**
***NEVER*** do this:

```
try{
   image = ImageIO.read(new File("spells.png"));
} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

never leave your catch block blank. At least print the stack trace. Otherwise you will have no clue if something wrong occurs.

---

**Edit 4**
You state in comment:

> Note on your edit: when declarations of the spritesheet and the sprites are put outside the paintComponent method. 20 parts of the code have unnecessary errors at variables and sometimes curly brackets saying `"engine.java:<line>: class, interface, or enum expected"`

From your error, I'm guessing that you've got code that calls methods, sitting out naked in the class outside of any constructor or method, where it doesn't belong. I suggest that you declare your Image variable in the class, and initialize it in your constructor (which right now is empty).

And again, you need to indicate for us which line is throwing the exception.

---

**Edit 5**
You state in comment:

> line 51 is spells[k][1] = image.getSubimage((34*2*k)-34*2,0,34,34);

And this is as I guessed in my last comment. This means that image is null, that your attempt to read it in is wrong. Often this is due to looking for the file in the wrong place, or if in a jar file, trying to use a file in the first place. You will want to consider getting the Image as a resource, not a file.

To debug this, try to simplify your program -- just create a very small program that reads in an Image, creates an ImageIcon from it, and displays the ImageIcon in a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, yourIconHere)`.

---

**Edit 6**
For example, try testing your code with something like this:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleTestImage {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String path = "spells.png";
      InputStream inputStream = SimpleTestImage.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
      try {
         BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

In this example, I don't use a File to get the Image but rather get an InputStream as a class resource. When doing this, Java will start looking for the image in the same location that you have your class files.

And again, read in the Image in your class's constructor.

Comment: When I run this code, I get spammed with errors in my console. Why would it do this? When the java file is converted into a class it has no errors found.

Comment: @user3502615: good, and also indicate which lines throw them. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: Note on your edit: when declarations of the spritesheet and the sprites are put outside the paintComponent method. 20 parts of the code have unnecessary errors at variables and sometimes curly brackets saying "engine.java:<line>: class, interface, or enum expected".

Comment: @user3502615: then you're doing it wrong. Show us how you try to do this, but post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23985626/edit). Also, please see **Edit 3** to my answer.

Comment: @user3502615: Please see **Edit 4** to answer, and again, you need to indicate for us which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: How do I fix this NullPointerException? Is line 51 referring to something that doesn't exist?

Comment: @user3502615: For the love of all things holy, ***PLEASE INDICATE FOR US WHICH LINE IS LINE 51.*** Cripes.

Comment: @user3502615: I can only guess that it is, `spells[k][1] = image.getSubimage((34*2*k)-34*2,0,34,34);`, that your image variable is null, but **you** should tell us as this is information only **you** have.

Comment: @user3502615: thank you. For a while it felt like pulling teeth trying to get info from ya. Please see **Edit 5**.

Comment: My image variable is declared in the try-catch statement, and spells.png definitely exists...

Comment: @user3502615: I didn't say that spells.png doesn't exist, just that you're looking in the wrong place for it. Yours is a common problem. Again, are you using a jar file? If not then you need to look for your image file relative to the user's directory, a system property.

Comment: I noticed that I forgot arrays start at 0... but when I changed the code (will put updated code after this) it still errored me

Comment: @user3502615: see **Edit 6** to answer.

Comment: This worked... yet the program don't wanna run. Also, I am not using a .jar file...

Comment: @user3502615: I'm afraid that `"yet the program don't wanna run."` tells us little of use. What does it do or not do? Does it die? Does it make you tell bad jokes? Does it show error messages? What?

Comment: The program shows a blank screen, at the right resolution with the right swing properties, yet none of the graphics are on the screen. The console (on linux!) is spammed with the error message above.

Comment: @user3502615: again, that's not "spam". That's telling you that you're trying to find the image in the wrong place.

Comment: How would the image not be there? It's in the same directory... should I do the link "/spells.png" instead of "spells.png"?

Comment: I didn't say that "the image is not there". Again, you're looking for it in the wrong place. I would get as a resource, not a file as per my edited answer.